# My workbook is 2 sheets. the 2nd looks in the 1st for a match on a name and returns the value in a cell from the row where the matching name is found

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I asked this question before and got an answer that worked well, however, it no longer does. I've spent the last half hour trying to find it on site but can't. So anyway, I'm like to attach a sample workbook where I've only included one row (the rest blanked out) as an example, but cannot see how to do so. I cannot figure out how the formula in the CheckStatus sheet is not finding the Status value in the Roster sheet. The formula I'm using is

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Roster,VALUE(E25),16),"")
```

I'm trying to return the value "A" (Joe's 'Status') but it keeps coming back blank. If I take out the "IFERROR" the results are "#REF". It worked last month in a different workbook but all of a sudden now, it doesn't. Where am I going wrong?

Since I can't find a way to attach a sample spreadsheet, here are the rows in question (using tabs). The column Status is in is 16 and the row the data is in in the Roster sheet is 217 (they could be pasted into a blank workbook).

Roster Sheet:

```
Col#==> 2   3   4   5   6   7   16
Row#    Name    LastName    FirstName   Post/SqnNr  Type    Status
217 Schmoe, Joe Schmoe  Joe  OHPost0797 1Year   A
```

CheckStatus Sheet:

```
LastName    FirstName   MI  FullName    LnameRow    Status
Schmoe      Joe             Schmoe,Joe  217
```

Comment: You mean this? https://superuser.com/questions/1708066/how-do-i-find-the-cell-value-in-workbook-sheet1-using-a-created-address-in-the-s

Comment: Can you see adding quotes around sheet name? #REF usually occurs when rage is invalid.

Comment: In `INDEX(Roster,VALUE(E25),16),"")`, you use the sheet name Roster without a range. It should be something like `Roster!$A$1:$Z$100`. Also what is in `E25`? And are you sure that column 16 (P) contains the status required?

Answer (score 0):

Am i assuming correctly that you enter the "row #" to look up in cell "N25" on the "CheckStatus" worksheet which then looks in the worksheet "Roster" & returns the "Status Value"?

If so the formula should be

> *=INDEX(Roster!A1:Z400,VALUE(E25),16)*

- I've used the range A1:Z400 as a guess, it can be adjusted to your tables needs.

But maybe you could use **Vlookup** searching the Name column looking for "Joe Schmoe" as the search criteria.

That would look something like;

> =IFNA(VLOOKUP(E27,Roster!A4:Z400,16,FALSE),"Enter Name to Look Up in Cell 'E27'")

- This would allow you to simply enter said name your looking up to get the required "Status"
- Be mindful that the value being looked up, ie the name, that column being looked up needs to be the first column in the Range for **Vlookup** to work.
- So in my formula **Vlookup** is looking in column "A" for *"Joe Schmoe"*, which is typed into cell "E27" on the "CheckStatus" worksheet & returning the Value from the 16th column of the table in the "Roster" worksheet to return *"Joe Schmoe's"* "Status" which is "A".

Hope this is what your looking for.

Comment: Thanks to all for the input. I did however, finally get it resolved. To begin with, my first column was set to number lines from, not the beginning (I skipped the title row) and that threw things off. I added that column in case I'd ever sort the file and saved it. I could then re-sort it to the original sequence. But to the point, I got help from someone on fiverr.com. The formula I needed was:   =IFERROR(INDEX(Roster!B:B,CheckStatus!D91)," ") - I was just too dense to figure it out.